# Differenza tra italiano e Italiano

Tags: word-usage, difference, single-words, capitalization

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere qual è la differenza tra le parole *Italiano* e *italiano*. Quando devo usare l'una e quando l'altra?

Grazie.

Comment: Quella con la maiuscola se è la prima parola di una frase, l'altra in tutti gli altri casi.

Comment: Dunque minuscolo, se non all'inizio di una frase, sia per la nazionalità che per la lingua parlata.

Answer (score 4):

Ero convinto che avessimo già una domanda a questo proposito, ma non riesco a trovarla. Ad ogni modo, procediamo:

In italiano l'uso della maiuscole è diverso da quello inglese. In particolare le maiuscole generalmente si possono adoprare solo nei seguenti casi:

- All'inizio di una frase. E.g. *Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura*
- Per i nomi propri (sia di persone che di cose). E.g. *Quel ramo del lago di Como* oppure *Dirò d'Orlando in un medesmo tratto, cosa mai detta né in prosa né in rima*
- All'inizio del discorso diretto. E.g. *Disse a' suoi liberatori: "Grazie tante, figliuoli"*
- Con le sigle. E.g. *Zingaretti è stato eletto nuovo segretario del PD*

Per ulteriori dettagli puoi consultare il [corrispondente articolo della Grammatica italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-delle-maiuscole_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)

Comment: Quindi, generalmente "italiano" si scrive con la minuscola.

Comment: O con nomi comuni usati al posto del nome proprio: “Ieri il Papa ha detto…”, ma “ieri papa Francesco ha detto…”

Comment: @egreg Hai perfettamente ragione, le regole sono più complesse di come le ho poste (v'è una descrizione completa nel link che ho messo alla fine della domanda), ma pensavo che non valesse la pena di mettere tutti i possibili casi particolari (che sono tanti) nella risposta

Answer (score 2):

Treccani [fornisce](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/italiano/) i casi in cui si debba usare la lettera maiuscola. Fra questi: quando si vogliono indicare le persone che fanno parte dello stato italiano (gli *Italiani*) oppure quando l'aggettivo fa parte di un nome proprio (*Repubblica Italiana*).

Va notato per chiarezza che la stessa fonte mostra come sia errato usare la maiuscola quando ci si riferisce alla lingua italiana.

Questa frase ad esempio è errata: *"ero bravo in Italiano ma non sopportavo la geografia"* perchè andrebbe scritta *"ero bravo in italiano ma non sopportavo la geografia"*.

Riguardo alle lettere maiuscole in generale si assiste ad un crescente utilizzo indiscriminato delle stesse anche per nomi comuni, uso probabilmente mutuato da alcune lingue straniere (ad es.: inglese, tedesca) e dalla pubblicità.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE! Puoi argomentare un po' meglio la tua risposta?

Comment: Ho provveduto. Ciao, grazie

Answer (score -1):

In Italiano, si usa la maiuscola quando si tratta del nome della lingua e la minuscola, quando si tratta di un aggettivo.
Es:

Sto studiando Italiano

Questo libro è scritto in Italiano

Quell'attore è italiano

La lingua italiana

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Ho studiato italiano per anni e non ho mai visto questa regola scritta da nessuna parte.

Comment: Che si usi la maiuscola per indicare la lingua è semplicemente falso: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/italiano (2.b).

Comment: Mai sentito dire.

Comment: I miei ricordi scolastici sono abbastanza fermi su questo punto. Esiste qualche indicazione nel senso che ho detto io (http://www.grammatica-italiana.it/maiuscole.html), ma evidentemente si tratta di un uso desueto o di un'indicazione fallace. Mi adeguo.